# How To Create Temporary Directory in Scala Unit Tests

Tags: scala, unit-testing, filesystems, scalatest

**In scala how can a unit test create a temporary directory to use as part of the testing?**

I am trying to unit test a class which depends on a directory

```
class UsesDirectory(directory : java.io.File) {
  ...
}
```

I'm looking for something of the form:

```
class UsesDirectorySpec extends FlatSpec {
  val tempDir = ??? //missing piece

  val usesDirectory = UsesDirectory(tempDir)

  "UsesDirectory" should {
    ...
  }
}
```

Also, any comments/suggestions on appropriately cleaning up the resource after the unit testing is completed would be helpful.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures) would help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Krzysztof's answer provides a good strategy for avoiding the need for temp directories in your tests altogether.

However if you do need `UsesDirectory` to work with real files, you can do something like the following to create a temporary directory:

```
import java.nio.file.Files
val tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("some-prefix").toFile
```

Regarding cleanup, you could use the JVM shutdown hook mechanism to delete your temp files.

(`java.io.File` does provide `deleteOnExit()` method but it doesn't work on non-empty directories)

You could implement a custom shutdown hook using `sys.addShutdownHook {}`, and use `Files.walk` or `Files.walkTree` to delete the contents of your temp directory.

Also you may want to take a look at the [better-files library](https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files), which provides a less verbose scala API for common files operations including `File.newTemporaryDirectory()` and `file.walk()`

Answer (score 3):

`File` in Java is very cumbersome to test. There is no simple way to create some kind of virtual filesystem abstraction, which can be used for tests.

A cool way around it is to create some kind of wrapper, that can be used for stubbing and mocking.

For example:

```
trait FileOps { //trait which works as proxy for file
  def getName(): String
  def exists(): Boolean
}

object FileOps {

  class FileOpsImpl(file: File) extends FileOps {
    override def getName(): String = file.getName //delegate all methods you need
    override def exists(): Boolean = file.exists()
  }

  implicit class FromFile(file: File) { //implicit method to convert File to FileOps
    def toFileOps: FileOpsImpl = new FileOpsImpl(file)
  }
}
```

Then you'd have to use it instead of `File` in your class:

```
class UsesDirectory(directory : FileOps) {
  ...
}

//maybe you can even create implicit conversion, but it's better to do it explicitly
val directory = new UserDirectory(file.toFileOps)
```

And what is benefit of that?

In your tests you can provide custom implementation of `FileOps`:

```
class UsesDirectorySpec extends FlatSpec {
    val dummyFileOps = new FileOps {
        override def getName(): String = "mock"
        override def exists(): Boolean = true
    }

    //OR

    val mockFileOps = mock[FileOps] //you can mock it easily since it's only trait

    val usesDirectory = UsesDirectory(dummyFileOps)

    "UsesDirectory" should {
      ...
    }
}
```

If you use this or a similar approach, you don't even need to touch filesystem in your unit test.

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar requirement to unit test my functions against sample files. I solved it using `scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll` trait available in the `scalatest` package.

```
import com.nag.SensorApp
import com.nag.repository.SensorStats
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll}

import java.io.File
import java.io.FileWriter
import java.nio.file.{Files, Path, Paths}
import scala.collection.mutable


class AggregatorServiceTests extends AnyFlatSpec with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  val testFileName = "test-files"
  val configMap = mutable.Map.empty[String, File]
```

Next we override the `beforeAll()` method, which can setup the tempFile before the tests. The corresponding `afterAll()` will ensure to cleanup these temporary files after the tests have been executed.

```
  override def beforeAll() = {
    val tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory(testFileName)
    print("The temporary directory = " +(tempDir))
    val tempFile = new File(osAwareFilename(tempDir, testFileName))
    tempFile.createNewFile()
    configMap.put(testFileName, tempFile)
    val myWriter = new FileWriter(tempFile)
    myWriter.write("sensor-id,humidity\ns1,10\ns2,88\ns1,NaN")
    myWriter.close()
  }

  override def afterAll(): Unit = {
    super.afterAll()
    val tempFile = configMap.get(testFileName).get
    tempFile.delete()
  }

  private def osAwareFilename(inputPath : Path, filename : String) : String = {
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
      inputPath.toFile.getPath + "\\" + filename
    }
    else {
      inputPath.toFile.getPath + "/" + filename
    }
  }
```

Once this setup is done, the `tempFile` can be accessed from the `configMap` and used in our tests.

```
  "The Aggregator Service" should "sum sensor s1 and s2 records ignoring NaN " in  {
    val fileForTest = configMap.get(testFileName).get
    println("File for test :: "+ fileForTest.toPath.getParent)
    val aggregatorService = SensorApp.main(fileForTest.toPath.getParent)
    assert(SensorStats.totalRowsProcessed == 3)
    assert(SensorStats.totalFailedMeasurements == 1)
    assert(SensorStats.invalidSensors.keys.size == 0)
    assert(SensorStats.sensorInfo.get("s1").get.sum == 10)

  }

}
```